# MySQL - Compare rows within group

Tags: mysql, domo

Using MySQL, I need to compare rows within the same group and return rows that don't match according to a particular field.

For example, say I have the following table:

| cust | note |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | foo0 |
| 2 | foo1 |
| 2 | foo2 |
| 3 | foo3 |
| 3 | foo3 |
| 3 | foo4 |

I need to return all rows that have the same id, but have differing note values. The resulting output for the above table should be:

| cust | note |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | foo1 |
| 2 | foo2 |
| 3 | foo3 |
| 3 | foo4 |

How would I go about accomplishing this goal?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a subquery for this

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT `cust`, `note` FROM tabl2 WHERE cust IN (SELECT Cust FROM tabl2  GROUP BY cust HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT note) > 1)
> ```
>
> ```
> cust | note
> ---: | :---
>    2 | foo1
>    2 | foo2
>    3 | foo3
>    3 | foo4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=efb4ab384cc2d34c56e5024673913554)*

Comment: Don't use quotation markup for code blocks (unless you're quoting a text that contains code).

Comment: And don't put table markup inside a code block.

Comment: @Barmar the block comes from dbfiddle and it is ok to do so

Comment: But if you take the table out of code formatting, you'll get a nicely formatted table (as in the question).